# Не могу нормально отобразить обьекты с БД на карте(использую MapBox+Django)

Tags: javascript, django, mapbox

В html файле инициализирую карту и запускаю цикл в шаблонизаторе Django и для каждого студента передаю его координаты и имя в файл JS. Проблема в том, что маркер всегда устанавливается на непонятную координату(где-то около Ирана). В чём может быть проблема?
[image: JS:]

[image: HTML]

Comment: Тут js ни при чем, ваши координаты и есть Иран [30.58295159374927 50.83369114545473](https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/30%C2%B034'58.6%22N+50%C2%B050'01.3%22E/@30.4886549,50.8914516,9.54z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d30.5829516!4d50.8336911)

Comment: это центр карты, а не маркер

Comment: маркер отдельный для каждого студента

Comment: А чем мы можем по скринам еще помочь? Какие координаты получаются в student.longitude и latitude (в HTML)

Comment: Для каждого пользователя вы запускаете initMap() и перезаписываете контейнер, в итоге в теории должна получится только одна метка. Вынесете вызов initMap() из цикла

Comment: @Greg-- там получаются нормальные координаты. А в итоге любой маркер/ независимо от его координат и центра карты добавляется где-то в Иран

Comment: @Greg-- вынес InitMap, но ошибка такая же

Comment: Сделайте просто демо в виде снипетта. Я могу сказать что [все работает](https://codepen.io/-greg-/pen/ExKzepV?editors=0010)

Comment: В где задается перменная `map` на приведенном скрине вы не смогли бы маркеры добавить так как map вне области видимости showUser

Comment: @Greg-- как лучше всего сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте вручную указать координаты как в моем [примере](https://codepen.io/-greg-/pen/ExKzepV?editors=0010)  упростить до минимального демо на кодпен или тут в виде сниппета. тогда исключатся другие проблемы

Comment: в общем, всё работает нормально, когда мы напрямую зададим координаты. Но когда я передаю в JS какие-то данные, маркер устанавливается неправильно.

Comment: Выведите каждый этап в консоль, 1. посмотрите в html какие данные передаются 2. какие значение присваиваются в _lat  _lng 3. выведите в консоль ll 4. Выведите в коносль color 5. выведите в консоль marker. Тяжело по скринам делать, сами понимаете ошибка простая но дебаг по скринам невозможен, возможно lng с lat путаете (пример из потолка)

Comment: Мы не видим данные, вы сами проверили если статикой все работает верно - где то проблема с данными, меня смущает как вы данные передаёте - в виде string строки и парсите её, есть в этом ошибки? - проверьте (до парсинга и после)

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Похоже lng и lat надо было передавать в другом порядке)